If A ∈ coNP, B ∈ NP and $NP \neq coNP$, is it possible to Karp reduce A to B?
If A $\geq_p$B and $B\in NP$, $A\in coNP$, then we can build a Turing machine $M_A$ using $M_B$ machine of B.
Input: w
We make a new word with a reduction function $f(w)$. Then we run $M_B$ on $f(w)$ and if $M_B(f(w))$ = 1 we return $x\in A$, otherwise return $x\notin A$
So $M_A$ is a machine that decides $A$ and $A\in NP$
But what if $A \in coNP \cap NP$? Then we cant say, that $A \notin coNP$? And the answer is yes to the question in the title, or am i wrong
